# Creat folder based on Dataframe in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, directory

I have this Dataframe. I want to creat folders with Id name and i want to put the images with duplicate id in one folder in path "F:/Images/" using python.

```
input:
              Image          Id
        0     00022e1a.jpg  w_e
        1     000466c4.jpg  w_1
        2     00087b01.jpg  w_e
        3     001296d5.jpg  w_1
        4     0014cfdf.jpg  w_2
        5     0025e8c2.jpg  w_3
        6     0026a8ab.jpg  w_1
    output:
        Folder w_e: 00022e1a.jpg,  00087b01.jpg
        Folder w_1: 000466c4.jpg, 000466c4.jpg,  0026a8ab.jpg
        Folder w_2:0014cfdf.jpg 
        Folder w_3:0025e8c2.jpg
```

Answer (score 2):

I think need:

```
#create Series for unique index values of dirs and lists for file names 
s = df.groupby('Id')['Image'].apply(list)

import os, glob, shutil
#get all images from folder  
src_files = glob.glob('E:/Images/*.jpg')
#create dictionary for lookup values from DataFrame
lookup = {x.split('\\')[-1]:x for x in src_files}
print (lookup)

#loop by Series 
for directory, files in s.items():
    #first create folders
    path = os.path.join('E://Images//', directory)
    if not os.path.exists(path):
        os.makedirs(path)

    for file in files:
        #get path of each image, if not exist return None
        orig = lookup.get(file, None)
        #copy files from DataFrame
        if orig is not None:
            dest = os.path.join(path, file)
            shutil.copy(orig, dest)
```